# Any way to receive multicast packets on Android Emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, multicast

Android emulator does not support multicast currently however I need to test an application that needs multicast packets. I want to do it on Emulator.

Is there a way to receive multicast packets on Android Emulator? I am open to writing some code as an android app.

Answer (score 2):

At the present time, 2 years later, multicast packets still not supported on Android Emulator.

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkinglimitations)

Answer (score 0):

Multicasting is still not supported by Android studio's emulator, however, you can use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). Using Genymotion, create two new emulated devices and set their "network mode" to "Bridge". Like this, the emulator will use your computer's network. By reusing your own network you can use multicasting if it is supported by your network. A nice bonus is that your emulators can even communicate with real devices on your network.